# how to make bottomnavigtion in compose like xml and java

Tags: java, android, xml, components, bottomnavigationview

hello i do this navigtion in xml project but i dont know how i can do it again in compose project i will put all bellow and what i tried for do that

[this is in xml what i ned to do it again in compose with the same look maybe and i will put the codes for it in xml and java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXOgE.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1D53AF"
    tools:context=".testMain">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="417dp"
        android:layout_height="602dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@color/home_20"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/nevc"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_item" />


</RelativeLayout>


java`  bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        // تعيين adapter لـ ViewPager
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

        // تعيين listener لـ BottomNavigationView
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        break;
                    case R.id.cart:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        break;
                    case R.id.massage:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        break;
                    case R.id.profile:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });



        // إنشاء BadgeDrawable وتعيينه للأيقونة المراد إظهار الرقم فوقها
        BadgeDrawable chatBadge = bottomNavigationView.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.massage);
        // تعيين القيمة الصحيحة لـ BadgeDrawable
        chatBadge.setNumber(1);


// تعيين النص المخصص لـ BadgeDrawable عند تجاوز القيمة 999
        if (chatBadge.getNumber() > 999) {
            chatBadge.setNumber(999);
            chatBadge.setVisible(true);
            chatBadge.setNumber(999);
            chatBadge.setMaxCharacterCount(3);
        } else {
            chatBadge.setVisible(chatBadge.getNumber() > 0);
        }


        // تعيين الألوان المختلفة لـ BadgeDrawable
        chatBadge.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
        chatBadge.setBadgeTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
        chatBadge.setTextAppearance(R.style.BadgeTextStyle);



        // تعيين listener لـ ViewPager لتحديث حالة BottomNavigationView
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });


        // تعيين عنوان الصفحة الرئيسية




        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();

        MenuItem homeMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.home);
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")) {
            homeMenuItem.setTitle(R.string.home_text);
        } else {
            homeMenuItem.setTitle("Home");
        }
// تعيين عنوان العنصر الثاني في القائمة
        MenuItem cartMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.cart);
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")) {
            cartMenuItem.setTitle(R.string.cart_text);
        } else {
            cartMenuItem.setTitle("Cart");
        }

// تعيين عنوان العنصر الثالث في القائمة
        MenuItem messageMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.massage);
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")) {
            messageMenuItem.setTitle(R.string.message_text);
        } else {
            messageMenuItem.setTitle("Message");
        }

// تعيين عنوان العنصر الرابع في القائمة
        MenuItem profileMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.profile);
        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("ar")) {
            profileMenuItem.setTitle(R.string.profile_text);
        } else {
            profileMenuItem.setTitle("Profile");
        }

    }

    // adapter لـ ViewPager
    private static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new homeFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new RewardsFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new chatFragment();
                case 3:
                    return new ProfileFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }


    }
`
```

thats for badges and for control with viewbager

and what i make in compose

[here is tthe nav in compose what i need in it is add shap or corner or any thing to make it like the xml nav i tried shap but got this error Unresolved reference: shap
i dont know i should make it in m3 or not for make that so i need help to know i will put the codes now(also i tried badge But I didn't see anything about it when I ran the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRPmc.png)

compose nav code

```
package com.example.esca

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.compose.material.BottomNavigation
import androidx.compose.material.BottomNavigationItem
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.Companion.Blue
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph.Companion.findStartDestination
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import com.example.esca.screens.HomeScreen

sealed class ScreensNav(val title: String, val route: String, @DrawableRes val icons: Int ) {

    object Home : ScreensNav(
        title = "home",
        route = "home_route",
        icons = R.drawable.home_24
    )

    object chat : ScreensNav(
        title = "massge",
        route = "chat_route",
        icons = R.drawable.message
    )

    object profile : ScreensNav(
        title = "profile",
        route = "profile_route",
        icons = R.drawable.profile
    )
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavHost(navHostController: NavHostController){

        NavHost(
            navController = navHostController,
            startDestination = ScreensNav.Home.route
        ){
            composable(route = ScreensNav.Home.route){
                HomeScreen()
            }
            composable(route = ScreensNav.chat.route){

                chatScreen()

            }
            composable(route = ScreensNav.profile.route){

                SearchScreen()

            }
        }
}



@Composable
fun BottomNavScreens(navController: NavController, item: List<ScreensNav>){

    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    BottomNavigation(
        modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,
        backgroundColor = Blue,

    ) {

        item.forEach{ screens ->


            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected =currentDestination?.route == screens.route,
                onClick = {

                          navController.navigate(screens.route){
                              launchSingleTop = true

                              popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id){

                                  saveState = true
                              }
                              restoreState = true
                          }
                          },
                icon ={
                    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = screens.icons), contentDescription = null )

                      },
                label = {Text(screens.title)}
            )

        }

    }



}
```

and the activty for nav

```
@file:OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)

package com.example.esca

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.esca.screens.ui.theme.EscaTheme

class ty2 : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            val listItem = listOf(

                ScreensNav.Home,
                ScreensNav.chat,
                ScreensNav.profile,



                )
            // remember navController so it does not
            // get recreated on recomposition
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            EscaTheme {


                Surface(

                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    // Scaffold Component
                    Scaffold(
                        // Bottom navigation
                        bottomBar = {
                            BottomNavScreens(navController = navController,  item = listItem)
                        }){

                        BottomNavHost(navHostController = navController)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}





@Composable
fun SearchScreen() {
    Text(text = "Search Screen")
}

@Composable
fun ProfileScreen() {
    Text(text = "Profile Screen")
}



@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun EscaPreview() {
    val listItem = listOf(
        ScreensNav.Home,
        ScreensNav.chat,
        ScreensNav.profile
    )
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    EscaTheme {
        Scaffold(
            bottomBar = { BottomNavScreens(navController = navController, item = listItem) }
        ) {
            BottomNavHost(navHostController = navController)
        }
    }
}
```